# Converting a website that uses FormsAuthentication to use OWIN Cookie Autentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin

We have a fairly large and complex site that is currently using ASP.NET/MVC's FormsAuthentication to manage authentication.

One complication is that the site has no access to any database, not for authentication and not for any other purpose.

The LoginController post action calls a webservice to perform authentication, passing username/password, and receives back a session token. If the authentication succeeds, LoginController calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie.

As is usual, all of the non-anonymous-allowed endpoints have the [Authorize] attribute set, which redirects back to the login page if the FormsAuthentication AuthCookie is not set.

What do I need to do to replace this with OWIN's Cookie Authentication?

Most of the demos I've seen involve a great deal more of OWIN's middleware than just the cookie authentication - pulling identities from Entity Framework databases, etc. There is no database in this website, and there cannot be a database in this website.

Any ideas?

Pointers to blog posts, MS documentation, whatever?

(This is in .NET 4.5, not in .NET Core.)

Answer (score 0):

Was supposed to comment but lack reputation so I'm posting here.

What authentication protocol are you using? Your use case seems similar to using Azure Active Directory for authenticating users.

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1) for integrating Azure AD to a web app might be a good place to start. It's using OWIN middleware with OpenIdConnect for authentication.

You can also find more options from its [main developer's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide). Under the Guides section, you can find the use of different authentication protocols and in the Reference Section, you can find the link to the code samples.

Comment: We're not using any of their defined authentication protocols - and there's no Active Directory in the picture. The webservice queries a database and returns success or failure.